# Multiple least square linear regressions in one command?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have 10 4*4 numpy arrays:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3, 3],
 [4, 4, 4, 4]]

[[2, 2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3, 3],
 [4, 4, 4, 4],
 [5, 5, 5, 5]]

etc...
```

What I want to do is calculate a least squares linear regression for each entry in the matrix.

So I want to take `m0[0][0], m1[0][0], m2[0][0], etc...` and calculate the linear regression. Then do the same for the `[0][1]` values.

Is there any way of doing this without having to first extract all `[0][0]` values into a new array and calling `numpy.linalg.lstsq`? Can I somehow pass my 10*4*4 array to `numpy.linalg.lstsq` so that it will calculate multiple regressions?

Comment: Are you trying to perform 16 (4*4) separate regressions? If so, what are you using for the independent (x) variable for each regression?

Comment: @Leo, yes 16 separate regressions. The x variable for each will simply be `xrange(0..10)`

Comment: Ok, I am not sure about passing it directly but extracting all 16 arrays is not too hard with something like arr.swapaxes(0, 2).reshape(16, 3). This assumes starting with 3 4*4 arrays. In your case you would use 10.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot... I'm sure there is a way to make this more efficient though.

```
def my_lin_reg(arr0):

    n = arr0.shape[0]
    s = arr0.shape[1] * arr0.shape[2]

    arr1 = arr0.swapaxes(0, 2).reshape(s, n)

    x = np.vstack([range(n), np.ones(n)]).T

    mc = []

    for sub_arr in arr1:

        mc.append(np.linalg.lstsq(x, sub_arr)[0])

    return np.array(mc)
```